# how to count rows over date and column in the data frame

Tags: r

I have data frame with 10 columns for this  data frame I am trying to get count over `year` and `val_1` with below formula. Which I am getting error as

> "unused argument (by = year)" in data.table

```
year   val_1 . . . . . val_50
2012    A    . . . . . 23
2013    B    . . . . . 43
```

I have tried to get output with below code:

```
df$cnt = df[,.N,by=year,val_1 ]
```

How should I modify the above code?

Comment: You are using `data.table` syntax on a dataframe. If you want to use `data.table`-syntax, you need to convert your dataframe to a `data.table` with `setDT(df)`.

Comment: Thus, you (highly probably) need: `library(data.table); setDT(df)[, cnt := .N, by = year, .SDcols = val_1]` to get it working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you're looking for count data per year, for each of your columns.

**Try using `group_by()` and `summarise()` with dyplyr**

```
library(dplyr) 
df %>% group_by(year) %>%
  summarise(count = n())
```